# Does destructuring create a new variable?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Let's say I have this:

```
const something = {
  someProp: {
    moreProp = 5
  }
}
```

with destructuring we get `moreProp`:

```
const { moreProp } = something.someProp
```

to get `moreProp` without destructuring:

```
const morePropAlias = something.someProp.moreProp
```

In order to access `moreProp` in the original object we need 2 accesses. My question essentially is that do we also need 2 accesses with the destructuring way or none at all?

Edit: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, I meant accessing 1) the destructured `moreProp` and 2) the `morePropAlias`. In other words, the alias var doesn't do any access (with dots) when we access it, because we access it directly. On the other hand, is destructuring just syntax sugar for us, so behind the scenes it still gets accessed like `something.someProp.moreProp`?

Comment: did you try accesing the parent object without the 2 accesses? did it work?

Comment: You could even do `const { someProp: { moreProp } } = something;`

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Not sure what you mean pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case two accesses happen. The destructuring notation is not skipping steps somehow.

In the following snippet I replaced the properties with getters, so that we can log when an access is performed:

```js
const something = {
  get someProp() {
    console.log("get someProp");
    return {
      get moreProp() {
        console.log("get moreProp");
        return 5;
      }
    };
  }
};

// Using blocks to get local scopes
{ 
    const moreProp = something.someProp.moreProp;
} 
console.log("----");
{
    const { moreProp } = something.someProp;
}
console.log("----");
{
    const { someProp: { moreProp } } = something;
}
```

In all these different notations, the number of accesses is the same.

Comment: I understood your question. But I think I answer it here: the notation is different, but the *actual* number of accesses is the same. With dot-notation it looks quite explicit, but the same happens with the other notations. What you call "behind the scenes", is exactly what I brought to the surface with the getters that perform a `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

when You wrote [some variable = access to data in object] you created variable with variable (created dynamically or not) from object if you want some action everytime you have to use getter or simple function everytime, it's clear and logical...  or maybe I don't understand ur question.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.